# Как создать загрузочный диск Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Насколько сложно или даже насколько возможно создать образ загрузочного диска Ubuntu?

Ситуация следующая, мы обычно берем флешку, с помощью *Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.6.8* устанавливаем на нее образ Ubuntu, выделяя при этом 4Гб под изменения. Затем ставим все необходимые пакеты и утилиты, после чего используем в качестве загрузочного диска `Live` с которым собственно и работаем, перенося с одной системы на другую.

Но проблемы начинаются на некотором оборудовании, например на ноутбуках с картами ATI. И в силу того, что, видимо, в конфигурации меняется какая-то мелочь (а, может, и не мелочь), флешка перестает запускаться на всех других машинах тоже, после чего образ приходится снова заливать на эту флешку. Так как флешки более не оснащаются переключателем `read-only` выход найти не можем.

Идеальным решением было бы создать из стандартного образа *.iso от Ubuntu наш образ, с нашими пакетами и программами, которые бы загружались как LiveCD (DVD) вместе с загрузкой самой Ubuntu. После чего мы бы записали этот образ на диск и пользовались им, не боясь испортить нашу настроенную систему.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать и вообще возможно ли реализовать данную систему? Посоветуйте, как быть с текущим решением?

С Уважением, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. А почему бы не использовать программы аналогичные Ghost - clonezilla. И скопировать образы дисков системы, потом загрузится с загрузочного сд этой программы и залить систему на принимающую машину?  это если цель - перенести настроенную систему на другой комп или создать backup-диск...
2. А что мешает использовать UbuntuLiveCD и с него инсталлить систему, либо загружаться?
3. и уж если машины в вашей сети, то создать образ сетевой установки...

[Форум русскоязычного сообщества Ubuntu](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=89491.0), [результат поиска Гугл](http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&newwindow=1&biw=1006&bih=607&source=hp&q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20ubuntu&pbx=1&oq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20&aq=2&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=0l0l1l731l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ea32a04e29e91c6a&pf=p&pdl=300)
Вообще погуглите эту тему - она широко освещена (и не только для Вашего дистра), так что не все так плохо...

Comment: Вы, видимо не совсем поняли задачу, @itan_hunt, @Justicet. Мне не нужно инсталлировать систему. Мне так же не нужен ISO образ. Мне нужна моя система на CD/DVD с проинсталлированными пакетами и программами, которые я использую. 1. Мне не нужен установочный диск, мне нужен LiveDVD с необходимыми мне пакетами2. С флешкой я могу загрузиться, внести изменения и они останутся, с диском я этого сделать не смогу. Поэтому нужно, сперва загрузиться с флешки, "укатать" туда все, что необходимо для работы, а затем получившееся сбросить на диск, чтобы избежать изменений.3. Машины не всегда в сети.

Comment: @Justicet, вот если вы мне подскажете как настроенную систему снова укатать в iso образ/диск, чтобы иметь возможность просто загружаться с него, буду благодарен.

Comment: Теперь ясно. [Создание Live CD с добавлением пакетов][1];[Тут описание как добавлять модули/пакеты и делать свой ЛайвСД на примере Slax][2];[Самое главное и интересное: он-лайн Reconstructor (но платно)][3];[Создание на примере Fedora][4];[Создание на базе Gentoo][5]. Выбирайте на свой вкус. Список, кстати, не полный...  [1]:http://doc.slitaz.org/ru:handbook:genlivecd[2]:http://radist-elvin.blogspot.com/2008/07/slax.html[3]:http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ubuntu/77517/[4]:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-fedora-livecd/[5]:http://www.livecd.su/createlivecd/create14.php

Comment: @Justicet, не нашел варианта, чтобы "слепок" можно было сделать с текущей системы. Так как часть приложений устанавливаются вручную из исходников. Кажется, только у Gentoo есть нечто похожее, но под нее может не оказаться необходимых нам пакетов и программ.

Comment: Не важно какой дистриб - надо взять идею. Дистрибы не настолько сильно различаются (если не брать ввиду внешнее оформление). Например, в Федоровском варианте вообще пошагово рассказывается как создать ЛайвСиДи с неоходимыми программами, можно попробовать указать и собранную в *.deb-пакет вашу программу... А учитывая, что многие программы присутсвуют в разных типах пакетов, то поле для деятельности...

Comment: За установленными у Вас программами не обязательно лезть в инет-репозитории: "загруженные apt, для обновления пакеты по умолчанию находятся в /var/cache/apt". Если подключится как локальный репозиторий для программы создания ЛайвСиДи - то это вообще шикарно.

Comment: @Justicet, во-первых, погуглить можно, но с учетом того, что даже вы, как человек "в теме", не можете мне толком подсказать что делать, я уж вряд ли что-то нагуглю. Во-вторых, если бы я знал все тонкости приложений, которые мы ставим, возможно я бы даже потратил уйму времени, чтобы собрать deb.

Comment: 1) "я уж вряд ли что-то нагуглю" - Не думаю. 2) я не так то уж и в теме, как Вам кажется. Просто если проблема стоит передо мной, то я стараюсь ее "разгуглить", чтоб понять. Потом пытаюсь сделать, ошибаюсь, снова пытаюсь с другими параметрами - я так же учусь каждый день, как и Вы, впрочем. 3) _"Ничто так не заставляет человека изучить инструмент, которым он собирается пользоваться, как личная заинтересованность в результате применения этого инструмента"_ (С) Justicet (моя подпись на b3club.ru)

Comment: Нашел вариант [тыц][1] читать раздел "Remastersys Backup: бэкап для Debian/Ubuntu">"В отличие от Clonezilla, которая напрямую работает с устройствами, Remastersys Backup устанавливается на компьютер, работающий под управлением Debian или Ubuntu, запускается под управлением этой операционной системы и создает ISO-образ системы, под управлением которой она запущена." Потом из этого образа сделать LiveCD[1]:http://www.xakep.ru/post/54799/?print=true

Comment: @Justicet, вот это уже ближе к тому, что мне необходимо. На самом деле я больше как пользователь этой системы, хочется помочь тому человеку, который постоянно перезаливает флешки. Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать

Answer (score 3):

Установите на свою систему Remastersys, но не запускайте... Установите в систему те пакеты, которые Вам необходимы и достаточны... Скомпильте на здоровье всё, что Вам хочется, что б было... Добавьте туда UNetBootin и(ли) MultiBoot. Эти программки того стОят. Вот теперь можно запускать Remastersys. В его настройках укажите, как назвать систему, имя пользователя, и т.д., и т.п.. Теперь можете создавать образ диска. Будет создана как сама файловая система, так и образ для прожига-закатки. В файловую систему можете добавить всё, что считаете нужным (обычно настройки из /etc...) и пересоздайте изошник... Затем с помощью UNetBootin или MultiBoot закатайте своё творение на флешку, но с Persistant-областью. Туда потом можно положить то, о чём забыли в процессе создания, свои обои, xorg.conf., настройки браузера и т.д... Пользуйте, да удачи Вам!

Comment: Делал уже все это. Работает. И вам спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Создать live cd из уже установленной системы можно с помошью remastersys http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

Comment: Да, да, спасибо, мы это уже обсудили чуть выше

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [MondoRescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/docs/mondorescue-howto.html):

> You can use Mondo to clone an installation of Linux. Just backup the crucial stuff and exclude /home, /var/log, etc.

Comment: возмжно ему не подойдет, ибо: "Вы можете использовать Мондо для _клонирования_ инсталлированной системы. Простого _создания резервной копии_ основных данных (с исключением) исключая  /home, /var/log, etc"

Comment: Именно, мне не нужен бэкап. Как таковой системы нету, чтобы делать бекап. Есть система на флешке с уставновленным набором утилит. Но теперь из этой флешки хочется сделать диск.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы блин даёте... dd if=/dev/sdb of=/home/user/rescue_flash.iso Где /dev/sdb меняете на путь к устройству накопителя (а не раздела на нем, а то не скопируется загрузчик)

Comment: 1. И куда я потом дену 32Гб?2. Как оно будет работать, если потом этот образ просто залить на DVD диск? Неужели загрузчик заработает?

Comment: 1. На свободном месте можно создать раздел и закидывать туда свежие пакеты, или бэкапить данные с восстанавливаемой системы.2. команда dd создаёт точную побитовую копию включая главную загрузочную запись. Любое средство записи CD/DVD позволит получить загрузочный диск, если конечно носитель с которого снимался ISO образ бил загрузочным.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Dex](/users/5/dex)](/users/5/dex): Есть в linux замечательная утилита "Xfburn" называется (Для прожига). Не сложнее Nero:) с простым, понятным-GUI. Все что нужно, скачать образ ISO, нужного дистрибутива.Разобраться в программе не составит большого труда.